# how to use shift operator in cout statement as it is overloaded

Tags: c++

I am quite new to C++, I know that shift operator in C++ is overloaded. But as how we can do shift operation within printf statement in C can we do similar shift operation in cout statement.

Comment: You question is very unclear, I'm afraid. Some code may help clear it up. What exactly are you doing inside the call to `printf` that you want to do with the C++ streams?

Comment: Add parentheses, then you can.

Answer (score 5):

Well, just try it...

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int k = 1;
    std::cout << (k << 1) << std::endl;  // Correct shifting - notice the parentheses
    std::cout << k << 1 << std::endl;    // Wrong
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
11
```

What matters here is the type of the variables used for the `<<` operator.

The parentheses causes it to be `int << int` which is the bitwise shifting. Without the parentheses it will be `ostream << int` which will write the `int` to the stream.

Comment: yes accepted the answer and it worked, 4386427 understood my question, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why question is simply down voted by few, even when answer is accepted. Don't delete my comment if you really can accept feedback.